# How to access multiple td data in Js from a foreach loop in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following jsp code where I'm using foreach loop and accessing each object of an array elements.

```
...
<c:forEach var="empData" items="${employees}">
<tr> 
    <td><a href="#" id="nameId">${empData.name}</a></td>
    <td>${empData.age}</td>
</tr> 
</c:forEach>
...
```

And I've a separate JS file with the following code snippet

```
$('#nameId').on('click', function(e) {
   //Here when I click on the hyper link of td, I should be able to access both name and age
})
```

So, here in the js file, How to access selected row's both name and age

Comment: Open JSP page in webbrowser. Rightclick and choose *View page source*. That's the generated HTML output. This is **exactly** what JavaScript/jQuery can see/access. You'll see that it doesn't contain any Java/JSP/JEE code at all. In other words, you would have had **exactly the same problem** with any other server side language which produces HTML pages such as PHP, ASP, etc. Your problem is not specific to Java/JSP/JEE at all. You would make yourself and potential JS/jQuery answerers much more easy if you just paste the generated HTML output in your quesiton instead of the JSP source code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delegate and IDs need to be unique, so use a class

```js
$("#tab1").on("click","a.nameId",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(this.textContent,$(this).closest("td").next().text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab1">
<tr> 
    <td><a href="#" class="nameId">John</a></td>
    <td>18</td>
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td><a href="#" class="nameId">Fred</a></td>
    <td>19</td>
</tr> 

</table>
```